# .net core circular reference of dependency injections of SignalR and Background Servcie

Tags: .net-core, signalr, background-service, hub

Consider this situation: There is a background service, which is needed to generate data by user input and notify web users in timely manner.  In the meantime, there is a SignalR hub to do two-way communication with web users. The hub will need a reference to the background service for providing user input, while the background service will need the hub to send notifications to users.  How do I break the circular references?

Comment: "The hub will need a reference to the background service for providing user input" -> this doesn't make sense, provide what user input and how?

Comment: The background service needs a reference to the hub, not the other way around.

Comment: The hub will receive input data from web users and call the background service methods to process these data.

Comment: I can use a controller with reference to the background service to accomplish the goal.  But would rather stay with the hub if it is possible.

Comment: "The hub will . . . call the background service methods" - No, not directly.

Comment: @user3670632 read up on mediator pattern